# How can I orient jPlayer vertically?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jplayer

I'm creating a website as a gift to my girlfriend and I want to include a playlist in it using jPlayer:

**[Website](http://jplayer.org/)**

However, I would like the player to orient vertically so it won't spill from the sidebar. I read the developer guide but I think I didn't see something like it.

Is there a possible way I can achieve this?
Cheers!

Comment: You can totally modify it to suit your needs using CSS/JS.

Comment: I tried it but stopped midway, hoping there is an easier way to do it.

Comment: No, that's the proper way, add CSS styling... Also, I'm sure there are a lot of skins for the player available online, you might find something you like.

Comment: I'll edit the CSS then. About the theme, blue monday fits my website color scheme nicely, so I think it's fine. Thank you for dropping off some comments.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I solved my own problem by editing the css for the plugin and omitting some elements of the player. This yielded a much better result rather than orienting it vertically.